# How can I set minlength and maxlength selected when user change dynamic select option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have added my angular js code.  can I do if I change any in select and set min and max value for input ?

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="field in fields">
              <span class="ui-select">
                  <select >
                      <option value="Small" ng-selected="'small' === '{{field['font-size']}}'">Small</option>
                      <option value="Medium" ng-selected="'medium' === '{{field['font-size']}}'">Medium</option>
                      <option value="Large" ng-selected="'large' === '{{field['font-size']}}'">Large</option>
                  </select>
              </span>
              <span class="ui-select">
                  <select onchange="changeoption">
                      <option value="Bold" ng-selected="'bold' === '{{field['font-weight']}}'">Bold</option>
                      <option value="Regular" ng-selected="'regular' === '{{field['font-weight']}}'">Regular</option>
                      <option value="Null" ng-selected="'null' === '{{field['font-weight']}}'">Null</option>
                  </select>
              </span>             

              <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength='0' maxlength="40" placeholder="{{field.id}}">
            </div>
```

please find a fiddle here

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkrgpjuw/1/)

Comment: the code pasted here is not the one in the fiddle...

Comment: i updated my code. I have to write separate function in ng-change or i can do in html itself ?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? i didn't get it.

Comment: when i select any option according to the object the min and max length should be get set for input field.